# Netlogo: Multiple patch variables vs. table of variables associated with each patch

Tags: netlogo

I have to model animal movement in a large landscape with ~50m patches. Each patch has around 10 variables associated with it, which determines, at every step, whether an individual can occupy it.

Would it be computationally faster to have a table with 10 variables associated with each patch or simply 10 variables per patch?

Comment: I have no idea about the computational efficiency, but code will certainly be easier and cleaner with 10 variables for each patch. But, more importantly, tables are really outside the whole patch context anyway; you can't use a patch as the key to the table, so you would have to have some naming scheme so that you could find the right place in the right table. And all the nice spatially-aware primitives like `neighbors` or `distance` would have no meaning.

Comment: You seem to be asking whether it will be faster to ask a patch for the values of its 10 variables or to ask a patch for its id (pxcor,pycor), look up the id in a table, and get the 10 values from the table.  Unlikely.  But more importantly, this is unlikely to be the bottleneck in your program.  More likely, you are looking up the values when you do not need to.